# MongoDB PHP. Обновление нескольких данных

Tags: php, mongodb

Проблема с запросом в MongoDB. Необходимо обновить одним запросом несколько данных. Вот пример запроса:

```
$coll -> update( array(
  array( 'article' => 100500 ),
  array(
    '$set' => array( 'a' => 555 ),
    '$pull' => array( 'arr' => array( 't' => array( '$lt': 20 ) ) )
  )
) );
```

А вот пример самого документа:

```
{
  article: 100500,
  a: 400,
  arr: [
    { t: 30, b: 12, n: 90 },
    { t: 10, b: 16, n: 60 }
  ]
}
```

Мой запрос:

1. Обновляет значение `a` на `555`.
2. Удаляет все элементы массива `arr`, где `t < 20`.

**Суть вопроса**: Надо обновить значения `b` в маccве `arr`. То есть, везде где `n == 90`, значение `b` надо поменять на `777`. Как можно дополнить этот запрос, чтобы "убить сразу 3-х зайцев"?

В итоге должен получиться такой документ:

```
{
  article: 100500,
  a: 555, /* Тут было: 400 */
  arr: [
    { t: 30, b: 777, n: 90 },
    /* Тут был элемент массива */
  ]
}
```

Comment: Обновить весь документ не вариант?

Comment: MongoDB - это не SQL. Совершенно другой подход работы с данными. Одно дело сложную выборку делать со сложным запросом, другое - делать обновление данных в документе. Нужно просто выбрать нужный документ, обновить все необходимые данные в нем и сохранить

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB не позволяет делать выборки внутри выборок. Вы хотите найти внутри имеющихся записей (которые вы выбрали своим условием) ещё какие-то данные и обновить только их. Так нельзя. Можете ознакомиться со всеми [операторами обновления в документации](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/).

Легче сделать следом ещё один запрос, который будет обновлять необходимые вам данные.